# Copy Table row to another table HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7wXD/)

I have two tables. When I click on one table row it will copy to another table, and I will change the button as my requirement. Please help me.

```
$(window).load(function() {
                var items = [];

                $(".addBtn").on("click", function() {
                    var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();

                    var newButtonHTML = "<input type = 'button' value='Edit' onclick='Edit()' /><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/>";
                    $(newButtonHTML).children("button").click(function(e) {
                    });

                    $(newTr).children("td:last").html("").html(newButtonHTML);
                    items.push(newTr);
                    newTr.appendTo($("#stopsTable"));

                });
```

Comment: you are not using Jquery right. why you placed $ sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At your example it was a wrong selector

```
$('#myTable.tr')
```

instead of

```
$('#myTable tr')
```

Check fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/V7wXD/7/

Best regards!

Comment: Sorry I don't have point for up vote can u plz up vote my post

Answer (score 4):

Js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function(){
        $(this).append('<td><button class="copy">Copy</button></td>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'button.copy', function(){
        var $tr = $(this).parents('tr:first').clone();

        $tr.appendTo($('#stopsTable > tbody'));
    });
});
```

Test here:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7wXD/8/